# How to prevent duplicate records in Rails within a bookmark table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `pins` table (like standard posts) and `users` are able to 'bookmark' each `pin`. However, I want to stop `users` from bookmarking the same `pin` multiple times, as it creates duplicate records.

The bookmark table looks like:

[image]

It takes no actual content as such, just a relationship between the `pin_id` and the `user_id`. I suppose they are the two fields I'd like to avoid duplication on.

In my app, bookmarks are a nested resource under pins, like so:

```
resources :pins, :path => "pin" do
    resources :bookmarks, :path => "bookmark"
end
```

What would be the best way to avoid duplicates?

My create statement is:

```
def create

    @pin = Pin.find(params[:pin_id])

    @bookmark = @pin.bookmarks.build(:user_id => current_user.id)
    @bookmark.save

end
```

This saves a record, with the users logged in id.

My bookmark model:

```
class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :pin

end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add uniqee validation:

```
class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :pin

  validates :pin_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }

end
```

However you will also need to set a unique index in your database, as all the validations can be a subject of condition race.

```
add_index :bookmarks, [:pin_id, :user_id], unique: true
```

UPDATE:

As mentioned by @engineersmnky, you should fork your flow on the result of `save` method in your create statement. Currently your application will behave the same regardless whether bookmark has been persisted or not which might result in user loosing his input.

Comment: Damn you beat me by 4 seconds I posted the same exact code word for word +1. You might want add a little bit about his create statement since it has no failure handling.